# Rails form validation conditional bypass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model

I have a rails model that validates uniqueness of 2 form values.  If these 2 values aren't unique the validation errors are shows and the "submit" button is changed to "resubmit".  I want to allow a user to  click the "resubmit" button and bypass the model validation.  I want to do something like this from the rails validation documentation:

> `validates_uniqueness_of :value, :unless => Proc.new { |user| user.signup_step <= 2 }`

but I don't have a a value in my model that I can check for...just the params that have the "Resubmit" value.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In my opinion this is the best way to do it:

```
class FooBar < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :foo, :bar, :unless => :force_submit
  attr_accessor :force_submit
end
```

then in your view, make sure you name the submit tag like

```
<%= submit_tag 'Resubmit', :name => 'foo_bar[force_submit]' %>
```

this way, all the logic is in the model, controller code will stay the same.

Comment: this looks like EXACTLY what I wanted to do.  I'll try it today when I get to work.

Comment: if you are using Devise and you don't wish to change the view, you could override RegistrationsController to set foobar[force_submit] in the params before sending it on to Devise::RegistrationsController.  Don't forget to set 'attr_accessible :force_submit' in the model (Rails 3.x) or the force_submit won't be updated.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

Rails 2: `Model.save(false)`
Rails 3: `Model.save(:validate => false)`

It bypasses validations (all of them though).

Comment: My title was kind of misleading...I dont want to totally bypass all of my validations, just the 2 validates_uniqeness_of

Comment: Just stumbled upon this. You should use `object.save(:validate => false)` when using Rails 3.

Comment: Good point Jaap, I've submitted edit to add that to the answer.

Comment: Is there a version of this for create?

Comment: Thanks for this; this is exactly what I want to do: skip all validations.  I didn't know it was this simple.

Answer (score 2):

Not positive about this, but you could try to add an attr_accessor to your model to hold whether or not the form has been submited once before.

just add

`attr_accessor :submitted`

to your model and check for it in your validations.

Answer (score 1):

You can just look at the submit button to determine whether you want to perform the validations.

```
def form_method
  case params[:submit]
    when "Submit" 
      'Do your validation here'
    when "Resubmit" 
      'Do not call validation routine'
  end
end
```