# Relaxing validations for 'quick create'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

I have a couple of models in my application that incorporate extensive ActiveRecord validations to ensure data quality, but because these require a lot of user input I'm also allowing users to **quick create** records by inputting only a fraction of the information typically required for a full create.

Is there a way to bypass a number of validations when I'm doing a 'quick create'?

Up until this point I've been doing `@project.save(:validate=>false)` and doing the necessary validations manually in the controller action but this is ungainly and creates redundant code. How should I go about this?

Comment: Check out this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423160/rails-form-validation-conditional-bypass), I think it is right what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet is borrowed from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423160/rails-form-validation-conditional-bypass) and modified it a little:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :project, :unless => :quick_create
  attr_accessor :quick_create
end
```

The following snippet goes into your view

```
<%= submit_tag 'Submit', :name => 'project[quick_create]' %>
```

All the logic is in your model, you don't touch your controller at all.